# How to clean up broken routes in minikube

Tags: networking, minikube

I've been using `minikube --tunnel` to expose services for development/testing.  I've gotten to the point where there are problems with the routing:

```
$> minikube tunnel --cleanup
E1116 20:25:40.294996  166763 tunnel.go:75] error cleaning up: conflicting rule in routing table: 10.96.0.0/12 via 10.1.11.168 dev tun0 metric 1 
Status: 
    machine: minikube
    pid: 166763
    route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.49.2
    minikube: Running
    services: []
    errors: 
        minikube: no errors
        router: conflicting route: 10.96.0.0/12 via 10.1.11.168 dev tun0 metric 1 
        loadbalancer emulator: no errors
^C
```

How do I return my minikube networking environment to a pristine state?

If I can get my system to a completely clean state, i.e. as if `minikube start` had never been run before that would be ideal; i.e. I don't need anything preserved from previous instances of running minikube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot the machine; this fixes the routes.

Run `minikube delete` to clean up anything else.